# Printing line of a given matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, methods

I'm trying to made a method that receives a matrix and prints its lines. For example:

```
line nb 1 : 3 2 5 6 
line nb 2 : 7 9 0 1 4 3 
line nb 3 : 3 5 3
```

I'd like to know why I cannot print the lines of the given matrix using this code. And also, why I cannot increment the variable `k`, that shows me the number of the line.

When I run this code it does not increment `k`. It always shows me the number `1` for the line

How can I fix my code?

```
public static void PrintLine(int[][] matrix){

for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i){   // Loop all long the lines of the matrix
            int k = 1;     // Number of the line
            System.out.print("Line nb " + k + matrix[i]);
            k = k+1;   // Increment the number of the line by 1
        }

}
```

Comment: You define `k` each time through you loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that `k` does not get incremented; rather, you increment `k` only to discard it immediately, because the scope of the variable `k` is restricted to a single iteration (i.e., within the curly braces). The following should work:

```
for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i, ++k) {
  /* work in terms of i and k */
}
```

which, in your case, simplifies to using `i` and `k` for the same purpose:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
  System.out.print("Line nb " + i + matrix[i]");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And do you know why I cannot print the line of the matrix?

Comment: [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33468878/3831400) seems to answer that concern. =) You might also be interested in `Arrays.deepToString()`, which prints the entire multi-dimensional array, albeit with less freedom of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your `k` variable is initialized inside `for` loop. It means on each iteration it will be new variable. With initial 1 value.
Move it's itialization out of the loop:

```
            int k = 1;     // Number of the line
for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i){   // Loop all long the lines of the matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out the scope of your `k` is incorrect, you can just use the value of `i`, also when you print your array you are getting the object reference details, you can use `Arrays.toString()` to print the values from an Array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
  System.out.print("Line nb " + i +": "+ Arrays.toString(matrix[i]));
}
```